# How to transfer data (text file) in the phone's memory card to your computer

Tags: c#, android, usb, buffer, android-sdcard

I'm doing one project related to the transmission of data (text files) between your phone and PC (via USB COM).

On the computer I programmed software language C # to receive data from usb port com.

On the phone I do not know how to transfer (push) data from the memory card com port. I also read through some questions on the forum but have not quite understand. As far as I know they want to do that we have to transfer data through the buffer and then pushed away by the support package in android (On my phone text files stored on SD / project.txt)
People can give me solution to handle this problem is not? 
Sorry if the reader was puzzled because I only speak english very much. I have to ask the help of http://translate.google.com/.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation for USB Host on Adroid Devices:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html